# inittab calls a script has su command

Tags: linux

I am using CentOS 6.3, I failed to add a script in inittab to let it start automatically.

```
myscriptid:2345:respawn:myscript_path
```

In the script, I have a `su myusername -c` command, if I run it directly, it prompts me to enter the password, then the script can run. So my question is if I add it to inittab, will it be called successfully?

Answer (score 1):

First, accepted practice is to never run an initialization script outside the standard /etc/init.d (or the newer startup methods) unless it is absolutely necessary.

Why not create a script, put it in /etc/init.d with appropriate symbolic links to /etc/rc.5 or /etc/rc.3 (as appropriate) for starting and stopping such a service.  The service command calls scripting in /etc/init.d.

So please reconsider reconstructing your startup scripting.

Now for the specific answer, if the scripting you have runs as the root user, then any su will not require a password.